# Openboard "Failed to start encoder" in the podcast feature

Tags: 22.04, dependencies

I have just installed Openboard 1.6.1 (via Software Manager) in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Once I try to start recording in the podcast feature, it says "Failed to start encoder" - the button with a red dot (that represents "record") turns into a black square (that represents "stop"), but the chronometer stays fixed at 00:00, nothing happens, and nothing is recorded. Is there anything extra I should install in order to make it work properly in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

I once had it working well in a Dell laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS; I only got this issue in this new Dell laptop, with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

EDIT: I just realized that it works if, in the Podcast feature, I chose the option "No audio recording". But then, of course, the screen is recorded, but no audio is recorded.